# Pitest, Spring Boot, Gradle Plugin Error

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, mutators, pitest

I am currently trying to add Mutation testing to a gradle project. I have successfully added it on a simple test project that purely has a noddy test class but I cannot seem to add it into the main project.

After much searching I have found no helpful solution. All that I can provide is the full stacktrace below:

```
15:08:16 PIT >> FINE : Running report with ReportOptions [targetClasses=[^controller\..*$], excludedMethods=[], excludedClasses=[], codePaths=[/home/dominic/Documents/API/Development/products/api/build/classes/main], reportDir=/home/dominic/Documents/API/Development/products/api/build/reports/pitest, historyInputLocation=null, historyOutputLocation=null, sourceDirs=[/home/dominic/Documents/API/Development/products/api/src/main/resources, /home/dominic/Documents/API/Development/products/api/src/main/java], classPathElements=[/home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.pitest/pitest/1.1.9/b9dcaaf81257e9f436c73e59579461d8405e34e5/pitest-1.1.9.jar, /home/dominic/Documents/API/Development/products/api/build/classes/test, /home/dominic/Documents/API/Development/products/api/build/resources/test, /home/dominic/Documents/API/Development/products/api/build/classes/main, /home/dominic/Documents/API/Development/products/api/build/resources/main, /home/dominic/Documents/API/Development/products/shared/vendor/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar, /home/dominic/Documents/API/Development/products/shared/vendor/com.stibo.multicontextsplitter.jar, /home/dominic/Documents/API/Development/products/shared/vendor/jms.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.16.8/2ce9de13f277ec1600e7e04231477e3e5f59d317/lombok-1.16.8.jar, /home/dominic/Documents/API/Development/products/shared/build/libs/shared-0.0.1.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.3.RELEASE/f1ee2657f50844d8682b30a1f40aebff3ad60cce/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.3.3.RELEASE/ec15d8ba682e5e287a6d8cb1299ca69214a46530/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.3.RELEASE/c1f8f3102650e54259d69c519b45b64fbf5cd25b/spring-boot-starter-data-jp                                                                                               a-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4.1208/5c7e80698b80a5045fe64daa67426051bbd16a56/postgresql-9.4.1208.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/1.3.3.RELEASE/f440856dcf4c3018c9005fa229e7509f28927a73/spring-boot-starter-test-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.skyscreamer/jsonassert/1.3.0/d5c250eb122496866de36dc84f98e2945845ecdd/jsonassert-1.3.0.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jaxen/jaxen/1.1.6/3f8c36d9a0578e8e98f030c662b69888b1430ac0/jaxen-1.1.6.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.activemq/activemq-broker/5.12.3/c069de6c92cfc7a8ba8ed8f419116b1b39b99e3d/activemq-broker-5.12.3.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jms/4.2.5.RELEASE/31050a9665e5d6fa0013d64f04eb653a4d557f6c/spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/b1b6ea3b7e4aa4f492509a4952029cd8e48019ad/commons-io-2.4.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/e4a71ce6ae8e42a7535dd9f1a39f91d36c538f28/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.3.RELEASE/541468d85cc2c94d2b538b0fa07c018847bb9b78/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.3.RELEASE/df2d5a437fa3093b8da99216c355189fe7b5e64/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.6.5/d50be1723a09befd903887099ff2014ea9020333/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/4.2.5.RELEASE/49cd2430884b77172aa81e3fc33ef668ea1dab30/spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.                                                                                                gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.5.RELEASE/cf463cce3e4453eb4b9a69de2dcdfd60c3c57e0/spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.3.3.RELEASE/7f1ae26c1ea42fb9dd5f14925cd605198f8b644/spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.3.RELEASE/f80c290f6a3dccb8255a594795a20048c63460da/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.3.RELEASE/f10ffeca4c879f1f66f30989cc0f133258934246/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/27a119fcc2b91c50e5285dd11158fac2c38c9d1b/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/d81aff979d603edd90dcd8db2abc1f4ce6479e3e/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.4.RELEASE/80b83510e67aa085b7d91d2d096d90133ec995de/spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.5.RELEASE/ed09517441a276db2a7e0e7b60a390c52b8093af/spring-aspects-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec/junit-4.12.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/e8546f5bef4e061d8dd73895b4e8f40e3fe6effe/mockito-core-1.10.19.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/4785a3c21320980282f9f33d0d1264a69040538f/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/file                                                                                                s-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/251207b29f0f38f61e3495a2f7fb053cf1bfe8c/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-test/4.2.5.RELEASE/60bd0ac25869d515717284b77644d0416d3a38c5/spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.json/json/20140107/d1ffca6e2482b002702c6a576166fd685e3370e3/json-20140107.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jdom/jdom/1.1/1d04c0f321ea337f3661cf7ede8f4c6f653a8fdd/jdom-1.1.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.activemq/activemq-client/5.12.3/ef63293e7ba56376bc35aaf4e250f18f6022954f/activemq-client-5.12.3.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.activemq/activemq-openwire-legacy/5.12.3/1a317e54785e31ac789523b20461dec2d50d0776/activemq-openwire-legacy-5.12.3.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/858d6c70909b3ce7e07b59fc936f8ccfcd81c0aa/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/fa992ae40f6fc47117282164e0433b71da385e94/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/a75e18322c7b362fe1daa26a245ae672ec0f3138/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-messaging/4.2.5.RELEASE/604103815489605ed609a742a6bbc708ae3db12c/spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/4.2.5.RELEASE/7395321fe937272d9b781a13985e04ab2dcd6210/spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/641cc375499d444e4efbc1801902260daa79758d/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/e7a4a25f74dac6b335ffabc43e3e8a6                                                                                                e3066340e/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/16b395c84f28b947f1c336aa461fda1e662bb3b6/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/d64fb662c9e42789149f5078a62a22edda786c6a/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.32/734ead0c803525cc9c7f283438101734ca9aac01/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.32/82adf8bd959fc046d55490e6f2ce67297c91d62b/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.32/5e664b357710a6c43cad2191404c2a9d0b82cdb3/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.32.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.32/237ca58dac66f438579750169e6cb297ac041c9d/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/fb18766b576aa6632bcfe9a20a023cbd52bf9769/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.6.5/65137ebf85056473b40c311f889601646a7612ba/jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.6.5/334369d7eff497f358b248c171dac0dd62c68f67/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/a42bdfb833d0be6c18429aea3fb0fba81f85c6e8/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.8/969c8d3d3d56db1e1c8721a03ef07d0c9ac3a2e4/aspectjweaver-1.8.8.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.32/55396c45fc8c34f31420a3b280fde4b1387b04                                                                                                4d/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.5.RELEASE/205d2f1b902eac16a2ece772dc5ac6090b7e0b6f/spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/3616bb87707910296e2c195dc016287080bba5af/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/2f437f37bb265d9f8f1392823dbca12d2bec06d6/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/536ac0021240d97db99c7d2983067cef1a6f3af5/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/5d3ccc056b6f056dbf0dddfdf43894b9065a8f94/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/2a581b9edb8168e45060d8bad8b7f46712d2c52c/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/5e731d961297e5a07290bfaf3db1fbc8bbbf405a/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/d9a09f7732226af26bf99f19e2cffe0ae219db5b/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/1.11.4.RELEASE/c2b1fd4dbf7dff772d6124bb35892759e8bf088e/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.2.5.RELEASE/60625981b837ba93e603d3068d69c6397ecb3ad2/spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/3a6274f658487d5bfff9af3862beff6da1e7fd52/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/34e48073884704ac987d3d1a1ab9b60e62028a9/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/ca                                                                                                ches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.objenesis/objenesis/2.1/87c0ea803b69252868d09308b4618f766f135a96/objenesis-2.1.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec/1.1.1/c872b46c601d8dc03633288b81269f9e42762cea/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.fusesource.hawtbuf/hawtbuf/1.11/8f0e50ad8bea37b84b698ec40cce09e47714a63e/hawtbuf-1.11.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec/1.0.1/5372615b0c04c1913c95c34a0414cef720ca2855/geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/235ba8b489512805ac13a8f9ea77a1ca5ebe3e8/aopalliance-1.0.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/92353eb144695bba80b31f7bec4f36d871f230ac/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/2d5b546c5557dcbf08c3a381d7dc9bd275a602c1/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/c5922f37c8a5e4377cfb543c549f10e73d72ede0/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/8613ae82954779d518631e05daa73a6a954817d5/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/dbbd699a1486ad0f2ed6f5af6cfed66acacb9056/classmate-1.1.0.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.32/71471069cea029dfdce0735337864c7d0a3d9992/tomcat-juli-8.0.32.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0/antlr-2.7.7.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/e84a2122e76f0b6503be78094ddf2108057ac15f/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/3136ca936f64c9d68529f04                                                                                                8c2618bd356bf85c9/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.1.5/16722afde74444716e299bee1f60aec9f6d1f0dc/logback-core-1.1.5.jar], mutators=[], dependencyAnalysisMaxDistance=-1, mutateStaticInitializers=false, jvmArgs=[], numberOfThreads=4, timeoutFactor=1.25, timeoutConstant=4000, targetTests=[], loggingClasses=[], maxMutationsPerClass=0, verbose=true, failWhenNoMutations=true, outputs=[HTML], groupConfig=TestGroupConfig [excludedGroups=[], includedGroups=[]], mutationUnitSize=0, shouldCreateTimestampedReports=true, detectInlinedCode=false, exportLineCoverage=false, mutationThreshold=0, coverageThreshold=0, mutationEngine=gregor, javaExecutable=null, includeLaunchClasspath=false]
15:08:16 PIT >> FINE : System class path is /home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.pitest/pitest-command-line/1.1.9/ed8bd8e7802ac2d037cc795f205207915fd8c777/pitest-command-line-1.1.9.jar:/home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.pitest/pitest/1.1.9/b9dcaaf81257e9f436c73e59579461d8405e34e5/pitest-1.1.9.jar:/home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.11/4e031bb61df09069aeb2bffb4019e7a5034a4ee0/junit-4.11.jar:/home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/springloaded/1.2.5.RELEASE/5286364198a1f41d028c1d758ef7e44d2b63d6b1/springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
15:08:16 PIT >> FINE : Maximum available memory is 3540 mb
15:08:16 PIT >> FINE : MINION : Installing PIT agent

15:08:16 PIT >> INFO : Sending 1 test classes to minion
15:08:16 PIT >> INFO : Sent tests to minion
15:08:17 PIT >> WARNING : Error while watching child process
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.pitest.util.PitError: Connection reset

Please copy and paste the information and the complete stacktrace below when reporting an issue
VM : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Vendor : Oracle Corporation
Version : 25.74-b02
Uptime : 1267
Input -> 
 1 : -javaagent:/home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/springloaded/1.2.5.RELEASE/5286364198a1f41d028c1d758ef7e44d2b63d6b1/springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
 2 : -Xverify:none
 3 : -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 4 : -Duser.country=GB
 5 : -Duser.language=en
 6 : -Duser.variant
BootClassPathSupported : true

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.pitest.util.CommunicationThread.waitToFinish(CommunicationThread.java:60)
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.CoverageProcess.waitToDie(CoverageProcess.java:35)
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.gatherCoverageData(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:133)
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.calculateCoverage(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:87)
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.calculateCoverage(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:49)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.MutationCoverage.runReport(MutationCoverage.java:110)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:103)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.runReport(MutationCoverageReport.java:76)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.main(MutationCoverageReport.java:45)
Caused by: org.pitest.util.PitError: Connection reset

Please copy and paste the information and the complete stacktrace below when reporting an issue
VM : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Vendor : Oracle Corporation
Version : 25.74-b02
Uptime : 1267
Input -> 
 1 : -javaagent:/home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/springloaded/1.2.5.RELEASE/5286364198a1f41d028c1d758ef7e44d2b63d6b1/springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
 2 : -Xverify:none
 3 : -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 4 : -Duser.country=GB
 5 : -Duser.language=en
 6 : -Duser.variant
BootClassPathSupported : true

    at org.pitest.util.Unchecked.translateCheckedException(Unchecked.java:20)
    at org.pitest.util.SafeDataInputStream.readByte(SafeDataInputStream.java:65)
    at org.pitest.util.SocketReadingCallable.receiveResults(SocketReadingCallable.java:62)
    at org.pitest.util.SocketReadingCallable.call(SocketReadingCallable.java:37)
    at org.pitest.util.SocketReadingCallable.call(SocketReadingCallable.java:12)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
    at org.pitest.util.SafeDataInputStream.readByte(SafeDataInputStream.java:63)
    ... 5 more
15:08:17 PIT >> SEVERE : Coverage generator Minion exited abnormally due to UNKNOWN_ERROR
Exception in thread "main" org.pitest.util.PitError: Coverage generation minion exited abnormally!

Please copy and paste the information and the complete stacktrace below when reporting an issue
VM : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Vendor : Oracle Corporation
Version : 25.74-b02
Uptime : 1269
Input -> 
 1 : -javaagent:/home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/springloaded/1.2.5.RELEASE/5286364198a1f41d028c1d758ef7e44d2b63d6b1/springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
 2 : -Xverify:none
 3 : -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 4 : -Duser.country=GB
 5 : -Duser.language=en
 6 : -Duser.variant
BootClassPathSupported : true


Please copy and paste the information and the complete stacktrace below when reporting an issue
VM : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Vendor : Oracle Corporation
Version : 25.74-b02
Uptime : 1270
Input -> 
 1 : -javaagent:/home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/springloaded/1.2.5.RELEASE/5286364198a1f41d028c1d758ef7e44d2b63d6b1/springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
 2 : -Xverify:none
 3 : -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 4 : -Duser.country=GB
 5 : -Duser.language=en
 6 : -Duser.variant
BootClassPathSupported : true

    at org.pitest.util.Unchecked.translateCheckedException(Unchecked.java:20)
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.calculateCoverage(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:103)
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.calculateCoverage(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:49)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.MutationCoverage.runReport(MutationCoverage.java:110)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:103)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.runReport(MutationCoverageReport.java:76)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.main(MutationCoverageReport.java:45)
Caused by: org.pitest.util.PitError: Coverage generation minion exited abnormally!

Please copy and paste the information and the complete stacktrace below when reporting an issue
VM : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Vendor : Oracle Corporation
Version : 25.74-b02
Uptime : 1269
Input -> 
 1 : -javaagent:/home/dominic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/springloaded/1.2.5.RELEASE/5286364198a1f41d028c1d758ef7e44d2b63d6b1/springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
 2 : -Xverify:none
 3 : -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 4 : -Duser.country=GB
 5 : -Duser.language=en
 6 : -Duser.variant
BootClassPathSupported : true

    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.gatherCoverageData(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:142)
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.calculateCoverage(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:87)
    ... 6 more
:api:pitest FAILED
```

Comment: What PIT and gradle-pitest-plugin versions do you use?

Comment: @Szpak 

info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:1.1.9

I specify no version on the pitest in my gradle file, so I am going to assume it fetches the latest?

Comment: By default it takes the equivalent PIT version - here 1.1.9.

Comment: You could run analysis with `verbose` parameter set to `true` to see if there is something more about the reason why the process ended abnormally.

Comment: @szpak that stack trace is with verbose set to true :( It still says error unknown. I have seen some results mentioning junit version but that is fine...

Comment: I've seen that error having old JUnit versions on a classpath (https://github.com/hcoles/pitest/issues/168), but you seem to have only 4.11+. Maybe Henry will have some other ideas about that.